# python file monitoring

Tags: python, python-module, file-monitoring

I'm working on Windows. and I want to monitor of system file.(access, open, write, modify)
What modules are best for what I need to do?
Is it possible to use python?

Thank you.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: related: [Watch a Directory for Changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html)

Comment: @wim: How do you recommend that that be used from a Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a cross-platform solution then I recommend you delegate to [PyGObject](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html) or [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfilesystemwatcher.html). You'll need to write your program as an event loop, but I suspect that you may not be far from doing that if you haven't already.